# Implementing sip through service in android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, sip

I'm developing an android app, which should receive sip calls. The sip connection should always be established, so i'm using service for this.

I've stuck with some issues:

1. sipAudioCall works only if I start it right from the broadcast receiver. What I need is
   to send the call to the service, then open an activity with accept\decline functions, lastly open an activity, where call should be started (and can be finished)- but it doesn't work.

   4. after setting sip for register, registration calls multiple times

P.S. I've tested a sip connection through main activity+ receiver, it works just fine. The problems started with service+multiple activities implementation

**manifest.xml**

```
      <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
      <service android:name=".SipService" android:enabled="true" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

**MainActivity** - here I check if service isn't running and start it  + sip permissions.

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ///stuff
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.UseSip) != Permission.Granted ||
                ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Permission.Granted ||
                ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ProcessOutgoingCalls) != Permission.Granted)
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.UseSip, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio, Manifest.Permission.ProcessOutgoingCalls }, 0);

            StartSipService();
        }

     private void StartSipService()
       {
         if (!IsServiceRunning(typeof(SipService)))   
           StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(SipService)));             
       }

     //its deprecated ,but works for own services
     private bool IsServiceRunning(Type cls)
       {
         var manager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
         return manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue).Any(service => 
                      service.Service.ClassName.Equals(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(cls).CanonicalName));
       }
```

**SipService** - it should register for sip + have binding for call accept\decline

```
public class SipService : Service, ISipRegistrationListener
    {
        public IBinder Binder { get; private set; }
        public SipManager SipManager;
        public SipProfile SipProfile;
        public IncomingCallReceiver CallReceiver;
        public SipAudioCall AudioCall;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            RegisterReceiver();
            CreateSipProfile("login", "pass", "domain");  
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public void RegisterReceiver()
        {
            var filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction("com.myapp.INCOMING_CALL");
            CallReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
            RegisterReceiver(CallReceiver, filter);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            Binder = new SipBinder(this);
            return new SipBinder(this);
        }

        public void StartCall()
        {
            if (AudioCall == null) return;
            AudioCall.AnswerCall(30);
            AudioCall.StartAudio();
            if (AudioCall.IsMuted) AudioCall.ToggleMute();
        }

        public void StopCall()
        {
            AudioCall?.Close();
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            Binder = null;
            CloseLocalSipProfile();
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        public void OnRegistering(string localProfileUri)  {  }

        public void OnRegistrationDone(string localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {  }

        public void OnRegistrationFailed(string localProfileUri, SipErrorCodes errorCode, string errorMessage)
        {
            CloseLocalSipProfile();
        }


        private void CreateSipProfile(string username, string password, string domain)
        {
            if (SipManager == null)
                SipManager = SipManager.NewInstance(this);
            var builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
            builder.SetPassword(password);
            SipProfile = builder.Build();
            RegisterSipIncomСall();
        }

        private void RegisterSipIncomСall()
        {
            var intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetAction("tattelecom.nateks.INCOMING_CALL");
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 
                     (PendingIntentFlags)FillInFlags.Data);
            SipManager?.Open(SipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
            SipManager?.SetRegistrationListener(SipProfile.UriString, this);           
        }

        public void CloseLocalSipProfile()
        {
            if (SipManager == null) return;
            if (SipProfile != null)
                SipManager.Close(SipProfile.UriString);
            if (CallReceiver != null)
                UnregisterReceiver(CallReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

**SipBinder**

```
public class SipBinder : Binder
    {
        public SipService Service { get; private set; }
        public SipBinder(SipService service)
        {
            Service = service;
        }

        public void StartCall()
        {
            Service.StartCall();
        }

        public void StopCall()
        {
            Service.StopCall();
        }

    }
```

**SipServiceConnection**

```
public class SipServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        private CallActivity _activityCall;
        private AcceptanceActivity _activityAcceptance;
        public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }
        public SipBinder Binder { get; private set; }

        public SipServiceConnection(CallActivity activity)
        {
            _activityCall= activity;
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;
        }

        public SipServiceConnection(AcceptanceActivity activity)
        {
            _activityAcceptance= activity;
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;
        }


        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            Binder = service as SipBinder;
            IsConnected = Binder != null;
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;
        }

        public void StartCall()
        {
            if (IsConnected) Binder?.StartCall();
        }

        public void StopCall()
        {
            if (IsConnected) Binder?.StopCall();
        }

    }
}
```

**IncomingCallReceiver** - should send call to service and open acceptanceactivity

```
    public class IncomingCallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
         public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;

            var listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener();
            SipService service= (SipService)context;

            incomingCall = service.SipManager.TakeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            if (incomingCall.IsMuted) incomingCall.ToggleMute();
             service.AudioCall = incomingCall;

            var newIntent = new Intent(activity.ApplicationContext,typeof(AcceptanceActivity));
            newIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            service.StartActivity(newIntent );
}}}
```

**AcceptanceActivity** - binds to service, if user accept call - open call activity. if declines - service.closeCall

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ///stuff
            if (_serviceConnection == null)
                _serviceConnection = new SipServiceConnection(this);
            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(SipService));
            BindService(serviceToStart, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
        }

        private void CloseOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serviceConnection?.StopCall();
            Finish();
        }

        private void AnswerOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var root = new Intent(this, typeof(CallActivity));
            StartActivity(root);
            Finish();
        }
```

**CallActivity** - binds to service , start audio Call and close call if needed

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (_serviceConnection == null)
                _serviceConnection = new SipServiceConnection(this);
            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(SipService));
            BindService(serviceToStart, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            StartCall();
        }


        private void CloseOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serviceConnection?.StopCall();
        }

        private void StartCall()
        {
            _serviceConnection?.StartCall();
        }
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the CloseLocalSipProfile() method.  The service should not stop.  To see if the service is running from cmd.exe you can use >Netstat -a which will give the state of the TCP port.  Before the client connects you should see Listening.  And then when client connects you should see the connection being established and the IP address of the client.  When the client disconnects the service should still be listening.  A service can support multiple clients so after the client connects you should still see the listening as well as the connection.

Comment: You can also use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  SIP uses a format similar to HTML and uses as the transport layer TCP.  When a connection closes in the TCP you should see [FIN].

Comment: Ok. I figure out that I should use a push notifications to wake the app on incoming call. Still cant get activity to answer the call though

Comment: I think you are closing the service in the code.  As I said you need to check the status of the listener in the Server by using Netstat.  It will tell if the Listener is still running.

Answer (score 0):

For 1. You need to use a ForegroundService when you start the service, instead of calling startService(), call startForegroundService(), and in onCreate of the service call startForeground()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add delay between binding service connection and starting the call. I don't know why , but it seems not to be immediately binded